# PhoneStateListerner GsmCellLocation

Tags: android-5.1.1-lollipop, phone-state-listener

I'm running an Android 5.1 project recently. And while LTE testing, I found a weird issue.

I want to get the Cid and Lac by using GsmCellLocation and PhoneStateListener

Here is my code of PhoneStateListener and GsmCellLocation:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
tm.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCellLocationChanged(CellLocation location) {
        String txt = "";
        if (location instanceof GsmCellLocation) {
            if (location != null) {
                //something process when location changed
                GsmCellLocation l = (GsmCellLocation) location;
                if (l_ != null) {
                   txt += "\ngetCellLocation: " + l_.getCid();
                }
                else {
                    txt += "\ngetCellLocation, location is null";
                }
            }
        }

    }
}, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_LOCATION);
```

---

```
GsmCellLocation l_ = (GsmCellLocation) mTm.getCellLocation();
String txt = "";
if (l_ != null) {
    txt = "getCellLocation: " + l_.getCid();
}
else {
    txt = "getCellLocation, location is null";
}
```

---

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

I try to get the location via LTE by using PhoneStateListener in my code.
But It was not working as expected. However, 4G mobile data is working fine.

Only using GsmCellLocation is working fine. I can get the Cid and Lac from GsmCellLocation class.

After tracing the source code, I found that onCellLocationChanged of PhoneStateListener and getCellLocation of GsmCellLocation are running the same function named newFromBundle.

When running getCellLocation I saw this function is working fine with GsmCellLocation(bundle) of newFromBundle so that I can get the proper Cid and Lac by using GsmCellLocation class.

But onCellLocationChanged of PhoneStateListener is always return null with newFromBundle.

```
public static CellLocation newFromBundle(Bundle bundle) {
    // TelephonyManager.getDefault().getCurrentPhoneType() handles the case when
    // ITelephony interface is not up yet.
    //switch(TelephonyManager.getDefault().getCurrentPhoneType()) {
    switch(bundle.getInt("type", PhoneConstants.PHONE_TYPE_NONE)) {
    case PhoneConstants.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA:
        Log.e(TAG, "create CdmaCellLocation");
        return new CdmaCellLocation(bundle);
    case PhoneConstants.PHONE_TYPE_GSM:
        Log.e(TAG, "create GsmCellLocation");
        return new GsmCellLocation(bundle);
    default:
        return null;
    }
}
```

It doesn't make sense. Why do I say that. I got three SIMs of South Korea, KT, LG U+ and SK Telecom.

These three SIMs are working fine with getCellLocation of GsmCellLocation.

KT and SK Telecom are working fine with onCellLocationChanged of PhoneStateListener.

Only LG U+ is malfunction by using onCellLocationChanged of PhoneStateListener.

I don't think my code is wrong. However, the vendor of the unit said I have to setup proper SubId to let PhoneStateListener initialized.

I'm a little confused about it. I don't have to set any SubId when using SK and SK Telecom, but why do Lg U+ need to do that? And after I set the SubId of LG U+, it still doesn't work.

Is there anyone meet the issue? This issue has already perplexed me for a long time.

Comment: I got the solution from vendor. It seems there has some problem in GsmServiceStateTracker.java